# Images uploaded using drag and drop option seems not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drag-and-drop

In the given code, I am allowing user to upload file using button or drag drop option. Once the image is uploaded the name of image is passed to some exif tool where it is checked for gps coordinates. If Gps location information is found the the marker is placed on that location on google maps. My code works fine with image uploaded using button and results i.e. map, thumbnail and Exif information extracted are displayed correctly on upload.php page. But When I upload image using drag and drop the results are being displayed on index.php page. I want them on upload.php once image is dragged. 
Can some one see where I am making mistake. I know its really long explaination.
Thanks in advance.

My code is as follows:

upload.php

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
// code for drag and drop
if(is_array($_FILES)) 
{
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])) {
$sourcePath = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$target_file = "uploads/".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$target_file)) {
?>
<img src="<?php echo $target_file; ?>">
<?php
exit();
   }
 }
}
$path = getcwd();
$cmd = exec("exiftool -a -gps:all ".$target_file. " -c %.6f", $result);
// some html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"> </script>
<script>
var Lat="<?php echo $Latitude;?>";
var Lon="<?php echo $Longitude;?>"; 
if(Lat!=""){
    Lat=(Number)(Lat);
    Lon=(Number)(Lon);
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="map"></div>
<p><b> Thumbnail </b></p>
<div id = "img">
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $target_file?>" >
<img src= "<?php echo $target_file?>" alt="Image not found" 
 style="width:150px">
 </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.js

```
function initMap() {
var uluru = {lat: Lat, lng: Lon};
var map = new google.maps.Map(
document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 5, center: uluru});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
}
$.ajax({
dataType:"json",
url:'upload.php',
data: "",
success: function(data)
{
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(data);    
}
}); 

// drag and drop
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#drop-area").on('dragenter', function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).css('background', '#BBD5B8');
  });
 $("#drop-area").on('dragover', function (e){
 e.preventDefault();
 });

 $("#drop-area").on('drop', function (e){
 $(this).css('background', '#D8F9D3');
 e.preventDefault();
 var image = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
 createFormData(image);
 });
 });

 function createFormData(image)
{
 var formImage = new FormData();
 formImage.append('fileToUpload', image[0]);
uploadFormData(formImage);
}
function uploadFormData(formData) 
{
 $.ajax({
 url: "upload.php",
 type: "POST",
 data: formData,
 contentType:false,
 cache: false,
 processData: false,
 success: function(data){
 $('#drop-area').html(data);
 console.log(data);
 }});
 }
```

Index.php

```
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="drop-area">
<h3 class="drop-text">Drag and Drop Images Here</h3>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand this question entirely. Explain "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Adam I mean image uploaded from drag.php has $target_file variable also. I want to access that variable inside upload.php, where i want to pass it to some tool.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment "image uploaded from drag.php has $target_file variable also. I want to access that variable inside upload.php, where i want to pass it to some tool", and from what we see of your code, you may be better off with just using your tool directly in `drag.php` :

```
if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$target_file)) {
  $cmd = exec("exiftool -a -gps:all ".$target_file. " -c %.6f", $result);
  ...
```

Now if you need it all in `upload.php`, the correct answer is that you should use only `upload.php` and deal between upload or drag&drop in JavaScript, using the script to send `$_FILES` to `upload.php` no matter how the user provided the file ([here is a good place to start](https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/)). If it doesn't work we'll need the HTML/JS code as well as more code from `upload.php` to help you.

Comment: I tried adding everything in upload.php but no luck. May be you can look at code gives better understanding.

Comment: It's better yeah, thanks. For starters, try to remove the `exit();` or move your `exec` before (`exit` cut the code execution, so your exec is never executed). If it still doesn't work, we'll have to go through each steps one by one.

Comment: Does not work.  I can not figure out where I am making mistake.

Comment: No use guessing then, ask your code to tell you ^^ In `upload.php` add a `var_dump($_FILES);` after `$uploadOk = 1;` and a `echo "exiftool -a -gps:all ".$target_file. " -c %.6f"` before your exec. If the echo show the expected result, try the command directly in your tool, if it work then it come from a settings issue (from your server or your tool).